# Issues with Reference Type Static Data Member, could be compiler bug

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-members, compiler-bug

I suppose the static data member of a class can be a reference type initialized to a global variable like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned int global =0x1fee;
struct K {
    int a;
    static const  int & iref;
};
const int & K::iref=global;
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",K::iref);
    return 0;

}
```

But in my VC++ [test](http://rextester.com/TGPBY6206), it can compile but produce exception when executed. Is it just a bug with VC++? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Do you intentionally try to bind an `unsigned int` to a `signed int&`?

Comment: no, just for testing the issue. no problem if I change'global' to signed int. So, it looks like a bug, but I want to double confirm

Comment: It looks like a bug indeed. By binding an `unsigned int` to a `signed int const&`, a temporary `unsigned int` should be created, and its lifetime extended to the destination reference variable (`K::iref`). It almost looks like MSVC does not perform that lifetime extension.

Comment: wondering if the MSVC team is snooping around SO looking for bug complaint. Should I somehow formally inform them about this issue?

Comment: Yes please file a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: You can reproduce the behaviour in a much simpler way. You do not need the struct at all; you can make `global` and `iref` local static variables in `main` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You just need chance the

> const int& k::iref

to

> k::iref

And you need to initialize the variable when you declarate, not out of its scope.